# Using if condition inside a for loop using batch script

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a script which need to be iterating through the file and checking a condition, when  it meets condition every time corresponding values should be stored to a variable and displayed.

```
for /f "tokens=1,6,8 delims=    " %%D in (test.txt)  do (if %%D==01 (set x=%%I
set y=%%K)
echo %x% %y%)
```

Can some one help me on the above code?

Answer (score 1):

The tokens are asigned to the nominated control (`%%D`) and then `%%E`, `%%F`.

Solution: replace `%%I` with `%%E` and `%%K` with `%%F`

**BUT** within a `block statement` ( a parenthesised series of statements) `%var%` refers to the value of `var` at the time the statement is *parsed*, that is, checked for validity, not at *run-time*, that is, as the value changes through the operation of the loop.

To see the value as it changes, the easiest method is to change the `echo` statement to

```
call echo %%x%% %%y%%
```

For more information, see any of hundreds of SO responses on the subject of `delayed expansion`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done as below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in ("C:\Users\JOhn\Desktop\Check\*.txt") do SET input=%%F
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims= " %%a in (%input%) do (
if %%a==01 (
set "_y=%%f"
set "_z=%%h")
echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j !_y! !_z!)>>temp.txt
```